# How to convert from String [] [] to hashset in java?

Tags: java, string, hashset

I have multidimensional data in String[][] format. How do I conver to hashset?

I defined hashset as 
        HashSet  students = new HashSet();
How do I convert data[][] to students?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What is inside your String[][]? A 2d list of students? And you just want to copy all of them in a HashSet?

Comment: Henri, you are correct. String[][] is a collection of 2d list of students and I need to convert it into hashset

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the size of your array:

```
String[][] input = new String[10][100];

Set<String> output = new HashSet<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        output.add(input[i][j]);
    }
}
```

To be clear, a Set doesn't allow duplicates. So if you 2d array was containing twice the same String, then you might end up having less item in your Set than the original size of your String[][]

Answer (score 0):

```
private HashSet getSetFromArray(String[][] arrayItems)
{
   HashSet hashSet = new HashSet();

   for (String[] arrayItem : arrayItems) 
   {
      hashSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrayItem));
   }

   return hashSet;
}
```